# How do I force sftp user to start in their home directory

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, sftp

I am using RHEL6 and I set up an sftp server through sshd. Here is the relevant sshd config:

```
Match Group sftpusers
  ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I have a user `sftpuser1` which is part of the group `sftpusers` and is assigned a home directory of `/sftp/sftpuser1/home`. However, when I login to sftp with this user, I get to `/sftp/sftpuser1`, and not the home directory.

How can I configure this user to be forced into the home directory upon connecting to the sftp server?

Answer (score 0):

Update this to:

```
ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
```

To this (assuming all users with have /home/ off of this directory):

```
ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u/home
```

Comment: I already tried that. When I do, I can no longer login to the sftp server with that user.

Comment: What does your /var/log/auth.log say when it is configured that way?

Comment: Jun 17 06:04:09 Linux1 sshd[31694]: Accepted password for sftpuser from 192.168.1.235 port 61030 ssh2
Jun 17 06:04:09 Linux1 sshd[31694]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftpuser by (uid=0)
Jun 17 06:04:09 Linux1 sshd[31698]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/sftp/sftpuser/home"
Jun 17 06:04:09 Linux1 sshd[31694]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser

Comment: You need to set root as the owner of the %u/home directory and create subfolders for them to access. If root doesn't own the main folder, then it won't permit them to logon.

Comment: right but im trying to avoid them seeing a subfolder....the "home" folder is the subfolder i want their session opened in

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried symlinks?